# How Halide applies Interval analysis?

Tags: halide

Can someone explain where and how Halide applies interval analysis internally?
Does Halide use interval analysis on an array-based data dependence test?

Answer (score 0):

It may be "extreme value test" which can be found in the textbook "High-Performance Compilers for Parallel Computing".
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/0805327304](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805327304)

It may be "interval analysis" written in another textbook "Introduction to Interval Analysis".
http://www-sbras.nsc.ru/interval/Library/InteBooks/IntroIntervAn.pdf

Both the above two are the same.